# Error using Poseidon: Poseidon::Errors::UnableToFetchMetadata

Tags: ruby, docker, apache-kafka

I am attempting to use the Poseidon gem with a Kafka container. However, I keep receiving the following error:

`Poseidon::Errors::UnableToFetchMetadata`

Any idea how I could troubleshoot this error?

Comment: This means that Poseidon is unable to connect to Zookeeper in order to fetch details about Kafka cluster. Could you provide some more details related to your particular case? Could you pass your Poseidon configuration?